# Removing the TaxonomyField in the Migration

Tags: c#, asp.net, orchardcms, orchard-modules, orchardcms-1.9

As I have been creating my own Orchard module I decided that I needed a couple of taxonomies via the AlterPartDefinition method in the ContentDefinitionManager(I've been following the Advanced Orchard course on Pluralsight) class. I later decided that I actually didn't need 3 taxonomies and now I wish to remove a couple of them. 
Below is some code how I added them.

```
 public int UpdateFrom10()
        {
            ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("ExercisePart", builder =>
            builder.WithField("Category", lvl => lvl.OfType("TaxonomyField")
            .WithSetting("DisplayName", "Category")
            .WithSetting("TaxonomyFieldSettings.Taxonomy", "Category")
            .WithSetting("TaxonomyFieldSettings.LeavesOnly", "False")
            .WithSetting("TaxonomyFieldSettings.SingleChoice", "False")
            .WithSetting("TaxonomyFieldSettings.Hint", "Select the category")
            ));
            return 11;
        }
```

How can I achieve my goal?

This is the course for those of you with access to pluralsight
https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/adv-orchard/table-of-contents

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty simple

```cs
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("ExercisePart", builder =>
        builder.RemoveField("Category"));
```

Comment: My God, if I had a dollar for every time someone misspelled my name *that* way :)

Comment: Ooh sorry man , pfffft had to double check twice hahaha Syzmon made more sense in my brain. Anyway thanks Szymon:).